# Angularjs using $parse and assign from within a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

Firstly, I am converting some code over to [@john_papa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13375/john-papa)'s [Angular 1 Style Guidelines](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) and having some issues trying to get a $parse + assign working from within a service, specifically '[Defer Controller Logic to Services](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y035)'.

I have created a plnkr over here - http://plnkr.co/edit/OfPVPKEJIUUmK5GCnT1t?p=preview

Change the value, then hit 'reset from scope' and it resets that value back to the pristine version. As you can see, my `resetFieldScope` function works fine.

Struggling to figure out how to get the `model.assign` back into the `vm` of the controller.

The documentation over on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse is pretty light.

**So my question:** how can I effect the scope (or in this case `vm` utilising the 'controller as' syntax) with a `$parse.assign` from within a service?

Is this type of 'logic' fine to live within the controller?

Comment: You missed main point of  'Defer Controller Logic to Services' - make reusable code. Your service is not even close to reusable. I saw quite a lot of angular code and most time $parse is used in directives and this is actually nice place for it. When using $parse you need full name, i.e. 'main.formdata.field'

Comment: It doesn't currently need to be reused, but I still want to hide implementation details from the controller, and keep the controller as trim as possible, so my question is still valid?